# Jquery：CKEDITOR Cannot read property 'GetData' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I use `ckeditor.js` to do TextArea Editor

To get the value, i used

```
 CKEDITOR.instances.content.GetData();
```

and i got this error

```
Cannot read property 'GetData' of undefined
```

so how can I fix it?

This is my code

```
<script src="js/Lib/CKEdit/ckeditor.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">test</button>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="txtFT_Content" name ="txtFT_Content"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtFT_Content', { } );
        function test()
        {
            var x = CKEDITOR.instances.content.GetData();
            alert( x );
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a wrong instance id and a wrong method name. Try it with

```
CKEDITOR.instances["txtFT_Content"].getData();
```

This should return the HTML content of that CKEditor instance.